# Cancelling a logout and returning to a shell

Tags: shell-script, shell

I don't actually want to do this; the Law of Unintended Consequences looms large over this idea. I'm just curious if the capability even exists. Similar functionality might be handy for some scripts as a break out step.

Suppose I want to write this into a `${HOME}/.logout` file:

```
#! /bin/bash
cd /path/to/git/working/project
if [ "$( git status | wc -l )" -gt 5 ]
then
  echo "Check in your work before you leave."
  <STOP THE LOG OUT PROCESS AND RETURN TO THE SHELL PROMPT>
fi
```

How would I do that last bit? Would a `break` do it?

Comment: `exec /bin/bash -l` - replace the current shell with a new login shell.

Comment: Also, always error check those `cd` calls. No I never filled up `/` because I forgot once, why do you ask?

Comment: would you consider a hack like overriding the "exit" and "logout" commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First configure a trap in the session for the exit behavior:

```
trap ~/.logout EXIT
```

If you want you can add this trap behavior to the bashrc, and then .logout script will be executed every time the users try to exit the shell.

And then you can write the .logout script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/git/working/project
if [ "$( git status | wc -l )" -gt 5 ]
then
  echo "Check in your work before you leave."
  bash 
fi
```

Then when you try to exit the session the script .logout will be executed, and the bash will show up to check if the user does the right thing. If the users does whatever is right with git, the session will end normally.